# StringBuilder json to Newtonsoft not the same

Tags: c#, json

Hi so i was using StringBuilder to build json but i saw C# had NewTonSoft got interested started using it but its not building the same json?

I don't see why it would not be the same?

StringBuilder function:

```
public static string GetUsers(UserData userClient)
    {
        if (RoomData.userList.Count <= 0) return null;
        StringBuilder users = new StringBuilder();
        users.Append(
            "{\"Cmd\":\"move\",\"areaName\":\"testing-1");

        users.Append("}");
        return users.ToString();
    }
```

NewTonSoft:

```
public static string GetUsers(UserData userClient)
{
    if (RoomData.userList.Count <= 0) return null;

    JObject users = new JObject{
        ["Cmd"] = "move",
        ["areaName"] = "testinghub-1",

    };
    return users.ToString();
}
```

So the return of StringBuilder Json is:

```
{"Cmd":"move","areaName":"testing-1"}
```

NewTonSoft Json:

```
{
  "Cmd": "move",
  "areaName": "testing-1"
}
```

I need it to be like StringBuilder but i don't know whats wrong...

Thank you very much.

Comment: StringBuilder doesn't generate Json, it simply concatenates strings the way the developers tells it. The two texts *are* identical though, only the non-significatn whitespace differs

Comment: Why do you want to produce the same whitespace? It doesn't change anything as far as parsing is concerned but it *may* be important if you wanted to store thousands of records to a file and process with a tool like Hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is the same and the difference between the two examples is purely a cosmetic thing; Your StringBuilder result looks like this when formatted as JSON. It is perfectly valid JSON.

That said, it is very easy to make errors when you hand-craft your JSON like that. It is easier and better to use the NewtonSoft Serializes/Deserializer capabilities.

```
{
    "Cmd": "moveToArea",
    "areaName": "testinghub-909",
    "strMapName": "testinghub",
    "strMapFileName": "Yorumi/testingMap_Feb19.swf",
    "intType": 1,
    "sExtra": "",
    "areaId": 2,
    "pvpTeam": -1,
    "monBranch": [],
    "monmap": [],
    "mondef": [],
    "uoBranch": [{
        "strUsername": "twilly",
        "strFrame": "Enter",
        "strPad": "Spawn",
        "intMP": 100,
        "intMPMax": 100,
        "intHP": 2231,
        "intHPMax": 2551,
        "intLevel": 5,
        "entID": 1,
        "afk": false,
        "ty": 417,
        "tx": 197,
        "intState": 1,
        "entType": "p",
        "showHelm": false,
        "showCloak": false
    }]
}
```

Comment: You can return a single line with the [overload that accepts a Formatting parameter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString_1.htm), eg `users.ToString(Formatting.None)`. This could be useful either to save some bytes or, more importantly, if the lines have to be fed to a line oriented tool for processing, like Hadoop. It's far, far easier to process records in parallel if each uses a single line

Comment: beautiful answer thank you :)